# Can miners see sender's information?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, privacy

The recipient cannot see the sender's wallet address, but can a miner see the sender's wallet address?  Can the miners see the IP address of the sender?  Moreover, what information of the sender can the miner see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The recipient cannot see the sender's wallet address, but can a miner see the sender's wallet address?

No. Neither can see the sender's wallet address because Monero uses one-time stealth addresses in transactions, never the actual wallet address.

> Can the miners see the IP address of the sender?

No. A miner asks a node for a block template to hash. There are no IP addresses linking to a transaction in the block template received from the node.

> Moreover, what information of the sender can the miner see?

Nothing other than transaction data, which a) uses stealth addresses as defined above and b) amounts that are encrypted (hidden). There is however the option to use an unencrypted payment ID, though this is being phased out / discouraged.

A *node* however can of course see the IP address of the peer that sent it a transaction. It will not know however whether that peer is the original sender or not though, as transactions get relayed around the network.